# Making 3d models in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

hy!

I have to make a animation for my school.

My cencept:

Make 4 Pictures from a person's head and wire them together to a cube.
Then i want to import this into Adobe flash professional cs5.

My Question:

Is this possible?
If not, are there any other rudiments to solve my problem?

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you want to do this in the timeline, you'll find that the Flash IDE currently has very limited 3D capabilities(just 3D postcards). You could try to import 4 Pictures, turn them into movie clips, rotate/translate them in 3D, then nest all those into another movie clip, but not only this will be slightly cumbersome, you'll notice limitations when rotating the 'cube' (faces not sorting, etc.)

Comment: I suggest using a 3D API like Away3D/Away3DLite/Papervision3D/etc. ...there's quite a few out there, and they can all do this simple task easily. You can create a Cube primitive in any of those 3D APIs and apply materials/bitmaps, but you might get nicer looking results if you model the heads in a 3D package like Blender/Wings3D/etc. and export to a format supported by the 3D api you use (e.g. OBJ,3DS,Collada, etc.)

Comment: can you post a link to a tutorial please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Away3D's tutorials: http://away3d.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use Away 3D. It's the only flash 3d engine which has a dedicated (and free) editor.

The editor is called Prefab http://www.closier.nl/prefab.
It lets you create and texture simple 3d objects previewing results in realtime right inside the Away 3D renderer (this editor is built on top of it) then you can export your model into the Away 3D compatible format. I had a hard experience trying to export textured 3d from different 3d packages to different flash 3d engines. Prefab and Away 3d is the easiest way to do the task.

To make coding in Flash IDE easier you should install syntax highlighting extension from http://away3d.com/downloads.

Pass through the beginner's tutorials at http://away3d.com/tutorials up to the "Manipulating 3D objects". You won't need to learn anything else 'cause Prefab will handle 3d object setup for you.